# Bound datatgridview not saving changes to tableadapter, and thus not to database

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a datagridview bound to a table that seems to work fine, but will not save changes to the database.  I am using the same code as I used in another project, which did save changes, so I am flummoxed.  Also, I have debugged and the save code is being called, just not working.  The code in the form calls a separate class with business logic.

Code in the form below:

```
    Private Sub frmAdminAssign_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ' Below is generated by Visual Studio when I select my data source for my datagridview
        Credit_adminTableAdapter.Fill(DataSet1.credit_admin) ' Foreign key relationship to table being updated (lookup table).
        LoanTableAdapter.Fill(DataSet1.loan) ' Table being updated

        admin_assign = New AdminAssign()
        admin_assign.FilterUnassigned(dgvAssign, LoanTableAdapter)
    End Sub

    Private Sub dgvAssign_CellEndEdit(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgvAssign.CellEndEdit
        admin_assign.SaveAssignmentChanges(DataSet1, LoanTableAdapter)
    End Sub
```

Below is code in business logic class called from above:

```
  Public Sub SaveAssignmentChanges(ByRef data_set As DataSet1, ByRef loan_table_adapter As DataSet1TableAdapters.loanTableAdapter)
        ' Saves changes to DB.
        Dim cmdBuilder As SqlCommandBuilder
        cmdBuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(loan_table_adapter.Adapter)
        loan_table_adapter.Adapter.UpdateCommand = cmdBuilder.GetUpdateCommand(True)

        Try
            loan_table_adapter.Adapter.Update(data_set)
        Catch unknown_ex As Exception
            Dim error_title As String = "Database Save Error"
            Dim unknown_error As String = $"There was an error saving to the database.{vbNewLine}Error: {unknown_ex.ToString}"
            MessageBox.Show(unknown_error, error_title, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

The data from the datagridview is not saving to the tableadapter, which I found out by adding the lines below in the start of the second procedure:

```
Dim x As String = loan_table_adapter.GetData()(0)("note_number") ' Unchanged, check was right row
Dim y As String = loan_table_adapter.GetData()(0)("credit_admin_id") ' Changed in datagridview but still null (get null error)
```

Comment: There is no such things "saving changes to tableadapter". A table adapter opens a connection to a database and executes SQL statements over that connection. At no point does it contain any data so it never contains any changes. The data and, therefore, the changes are contained in the `DataTable`. If that `DataTable` is bound to a `DataGridView` then what you see in the grid is the data stored in the table. Any changes you make in the grid MUST be made to the table. When you call `Update` on the table adapter, those changes are saved to the database.

Comment: When you call `Update` on a table adapter there are only three possible outcomes. 1: the call fails and an exception is thrown. 2: the call succeeds and returns zero, meaning that there were no changes to save. 3: the call succeeds and returns a non-zero value, meaning that there were that many changes to save and they were saved. Which is it in your case?

Comment: Also, you really ought to be handling the `CellValueChanged` event rather than `CellEndEdit` what's the point of saving changes after an editing session if no changes were made?

Comment: Finally, stop declaring method parameters `ByRef` for no reason. `ByVal` is the default for a reason. Only declare parameters `ByRef` when they need to be. If you don't know the circumstances unde4r which they need to be, you should learn. It's well less than 1% of the time that you'd need to.

Comment: I thought the SQLCommandBuilder seemed like it should be unnecessary, but this is how I learned it and it worked.  The simple update also works and is better for sure, thanks.  ByRef is needed for the datagridview when filtering since I am passing it to another class, and the same with the DataSet1.  Otherwise, I agree everything else should be ByVal, and the extra ByRef as per my answer is what caused my issue.

Comment: *"I thought the SQLCommandBuilder seemed like it should be unnecessary, but this is how I learned it"*. The point of a command builder is to generate action commands automatically based on a `SELECT` statement. In the table adapters in a typed `Dataset`, that is done by the wizard when you generate the Data Source.

Comment: *"ByRef is needed for the datagridview when filtering since I am passing it to another class, and the same with the DataSet1"*. That is absolutely false. Remove the `ByRef` and you will see that it still works exactly as expected. You should spend some time learning what it actually means to pass by value and pass by reference and when you actually need to pass by reference.

Comment: You are right, it does work.  I thought ByVal is passing a copy, and changes don't effect the original.  So, if I pass in a datagridview to a procedure in another class ByVal and then filter it, I am not sure how the original is getting updated.  I will look into this.

Comment: `ByVal` does pass copy - of the contents of the variable. If the variable is a reference type, i.e. a class, then the variable contains a reference to an object so it is that reference that is copied, not the object itself. The copy still refers to the same object as the original. That's the whole point of reference types in the first place. If it wasn't the case then assigning any variable to another variable would be creating a copy of possibly very large and complex objects.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, it was related to a filter routine that is not above where I passed a tableadapter byref when I should have passed a datatable byval.  So, related to one of jmcilhinney's byref vs byval comments above.  See problem code below:

```
Public Sub FilterUnassigned(ByRef dgv_assigned As DataGridView, loan_table_adapter As DataSet1TableAdapters.loanTableAdapter)
        ' Should have passed in DataSet1.loan DataTable ByVal and used it below:
        Dim unassigned_loans As DataView = loan_table_adapter.GetData().DefaultView()
        unassigned_loans.RowFilter = "request_date Is Not Null AND numerated_assigned_user Is Null"
        dgv_assigned.DataSource = unassigned_loans
    End Sub
```

Also, skipping the SQLCommandBuilder commands and my code still works.  So, all I need is one line as per jmcilhinney instead of 4 (excl error handling) as per below:

```
 Try
            loan_table_adapter.Update(data_set)
        Catch unknown_ex As Exception
            Dim error_title As String = "Database Save Error"
            Dim unknown_error As String = $"There was an error saving to the database.  Please contact Kevin Strickler to resolve.{vbNewLine}Error: {unknown_ex.ToString}"
            MessageBox.Show(unknown_error, error_title, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
        End Try
```